# Disable java networkaddress.cache.ttl from chef?

Tags: chef-infra

I want to set `networkaddress.cache.ttl` to 0 in `java.security` from the opscode chef cookbook. I don't see an obvious way to do this.

Am I missing something, or do I need to write something to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the main `java` cookbook has anything for this, so yes you'll have to write it yourself. You can either do this in your Java code (`java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl" , "60");`) or use a `template` resource to write out the file. My Java-fu is a little rusty, but I think what you want is `"#{node['java']['java_home']}/lib/security"`.

Comment: Ah, that's a bummer. It's a common thing to disable, so perhaps I'll find a way to include it.

Comment: Sure, you could look at patching this in to the main java cookbook and contributing it back.